# Ant tar fileset exclude ALL subdirs but one using pattern

Tags: java, ant, fileset

I am trying to build a simple build.xml to create a tar ball with certain conditions. I have tried all possible options but, doesn't achieve what I am looking for.

I am looking for some sort of wild card which I can use to exclude all, and use pattern to include only those subdirs which are needed.

Below is sample source Dir. It has around 30 sub dirs, like prompts, audio, video, etc. Each of these sub dirs has multiple sub dirs with specific languages like en, fr-fr, etc. Each of lang dirs has some files like .au, .txt. htm, etc.

## Source Dir:

Locale/

```
  `-- prompts
      |-- en
          |-- some files
      |-- en-gb
          |-- some files
      |-- fr-FR
          |-- some files
      |-- es-ES
          |-- some files

  `-- audio
      |-- en
          |-- some files
      |-- en-gb
          |-- some files
      |-- fr-FR
            |-- some files
      |-- es-ES
            |-- some files
  `-- video
        |-- en
            |-- some files
        |-- en-gb
            |-- some files
        |-- fr-FR
            |-- some files
        |-- es-ES
            |-- some files
```

What I am trying is after ant run, it will create a tar with specific language files only and exclude all.So final tar should look some thing as below for fr-Fr lang pack. I am planing to use -Darg=fr-FR as argument to ant on cmd, to select which lang pack I want to create. this way I can create any lang pack, with only those specific files.

Locale/

```
  `-- prompts
      |-- fr-FR
          |-- some files

  `-- audio
      |-- fr-FR
            |-- some files

  `-- video
        |-- fr-FR
            |-- some files
```

Comment: Just to add more info, I tried using   <tar destfile="${release-file}" compression="gzip" excludes="**/**/*.*" > <include name="**/${arg}/audio/*.au" />. But still I am getting all lang dirs included. Excluding everything with specifying all dir name is not an option, as I need to create any specific lang pack as needed with providing lang name by -Darg. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

In order for a file to be selected, it must match `includes` and must not match `excludes`.  There is no such "excludes except" mechanism.  Try specifying the include only.

Comment: Hello Brett, Thanks for your suggestions. I tried what you suggested, i.e. specifying include only. But unfortunately, still doesnt work. In final tar, I still get all other dirs as well.

Comment: Below is sample of what I tried.  <tar destfile="${release-file}" compression="gzip" >
      <tarfileset dir="${basedir}/prompts"
              prefix="prompts" >
       </tarfileset>
<tarfileset dir="${basedir}/prompts/audio/"
              prefix="prompts/audio/">
           <include name="**/${lang}/*.*" />
      </tarfileset>
I get all Files under audio, but for all langs. I want only for $lang, if $lang =fr-FR, then include files under prompts/audio/fr-Fr/ only. Currently it will have files under prompts/audio/fr-Fr/  and prompts/audio/en/ and so on. Can you please help ?

Comment: Why do you have the first tarfileset at all?  Why not simply `<tarfile dir="${basedir}" includes="*/${lang}/**"/>`?